# How can I get constant name and constant value in file

Tags: php

I have files with texts an constants. How can I get constant name and constant value. Problem is that constant value has sometime spaces. I read files with `file()` and then with `foreach`...

Example:

```
define('LNG_UTF-8',         'Universal Alphabet (UTF-8)');
define('LNG_ISO-8859-1',   'Western Alphabet (ISO-8859-1)');
define('LNG_CustomFieldsName', 'Custom Field');
define('LNG_CustomFieldsType', 'Type');
```

I already tried:

to get constant name:

```
$getConstant1 = strpos($mainFileArray[$i], '(\'');
$getConstant2 = strpos($mainFileArray[$i], '\',');              
$const = substr($mainFileArray[$i], $getConstant1 + 2, $getConstant2 - $getConstant1 - 2);
```

to get constant value

```
$position1 = strpos($file[$i], '\',');
$position2 = strpos($file[$i], '\');');

$rest = substr($file[$i], $position1 + 3, $position2 - $position1 - 2);
```

but not working when is space or ','...

How can i make this always working??

Comment: Why can't you simply `include` the file and use the constants as constants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular expression matching this would be this:

```
preg_match("/define\(\s*'([^']*)'\s*,\s*'([^']*)'\s*\)/i", $line, $match);
echo $match[1], $match[2];
```

See http://rubular.com/r/m9plE2qQeT.

However, that only works if the strings are single quoted `'`, don't contain escaped quotes, the strings are not concatenated etc. For example, this would break:

```
define('LNG_UTF-8', "Universal Alphabet (UTF-8)");
define('LNG_UTF-8', 'Universal \'Alphabet\' (UTF-8)');
define('LNG_UTF-8', 'Universal Alphabet ' . '(UTF-8)');
// and many similar
```

To make at least the first two work, you should use [`token_get_all`](http://php.net/token_get_all) to *parse* the PHP file according to PHP parsing rules, then go through the resulting tokens and extract the values you need.
To make all cases work, you need to actually *evaluate* the PHP code, i.e. `include` the file and then simply access the constants as constants in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`get_defined_constants()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-constants.php) function for that. It returns an associative array with the names of all the constants and their values.